# How can I get rid off error "signal 11: SIGSEGV" in my PyQt5 app for controlling a webcam?

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt5, segmentation-fault

I am writing an application to control a multi-locker safe with face recognition and I've come across a problem that I've succesfuly replicated in a much smaller app (code below).
**Much shorter code at the end of the post in UPDATE #3**

To combine PyQt5 and OpenCV I followed the [tutorial by docPhil99 on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/docPhil99/ca4da12c9d6f29b9cea137b617c7b8b1).

Whenever I try closing and opening a webcam by using a QThread after a couple of times I get an error:
`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

I am using PyCharm CE with Python 3.10 from Anaconda on MacOS 13.2.1
OpenCV 4.7.0
PyQt5

```
class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.cv_img = None
        self.ret = None
        self.camera_needed = False

    def run(self):
        # capture from webcam
        self.camera_needed = True
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
        while self.camera_needed:
            self.ret, self.cv_img = self.cap.read()
            if self.ret:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(self.cv_img)

    def stop(self):
        self.cap.release()
        self.camera_needed = False
        self.exit(0)


class TestWindowForCameraOpenAndClose(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.video_thread = VideoThread()
        self.video_thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.refresh_video)

        self.ui()

    def ui(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.camera_preview = QLabel(self)
        self.camera_preview.resize(480, 320)

        turn_on_btn = QPushButton('ON', self)
        turn_on_btn.clicked.connect(self.turn_on)

        turn_off_btn = QPushButton('OFF', self)
        turn_off_btn.clicked.connect(self.turn_off)

        layout.addWidget(self.camera_preview)
        layout.addWidget(turn_on_btn)
        layout.addWidget(turn_off_btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def turn_on(self):
        self.video_thread.start()

    def turn_off(self):
        self.video_thread.stop()

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def refresh_video(self, cv_img):
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.camera_preview.setPixmap(qt_img)

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_img.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_img.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = qt_format.scaled(480, 320, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = TestWindowForCameraOpenAndClose()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

This program here is obviously very simplified but it gives the same error.

I expected it to open the webcam when pressing ON, and closing when pressing OFF.

---- UPDATE ----
Try/except doesn't seem to help here as it doesn't catch this error.

---- UPDATE #2 ----
When running the same code on Windows 10 in PyCharm, Python 3.10 from Anaconda instead of a segmentation fault I get this error, but the program continues.
`[ WARN:0@16.708] global cap_msmf.cpp:1759 CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638`

---- UPDATE #3 ----
I tried testing just the camera in OpenCV

```
import cv2

camera_preview = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not camera_preview.isOpened():
    exit()

while (True):
    camera_preview = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = camera_preview.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(0):
        break

camera_preview.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

which should give me a video preview, but I only get a still frame and no video. There is however no segmentation fault error here.

I'm starting to feel that this is an OpenCV fault here.

I'm honestly out of ideas and sadly I haven't yet fully understood QThreads and I'm running out of time to finish my application for my university course.
Thank you in advance,
Artur

Comment: Does the SIGSEGV always happen, or only occasionally? When does it happen: at program startup time, or when you do a specific action?

Comment: Your Python code looks fine, maybe the libraries you are using are buggy. (It's not your fault.) You may want to ask your professor for advice and opinion. Maybe you can get maximum score for this assignment even without fixing the SIGSEGV.

Comment: SIGSEGV means that the program tried to access a memory region it doesn't have permission for. It usually indicates a bug in the (C or C++) program. However, Python code bugs typically cause Python exceptions (and almost never SIGSEGV). So the bug in your program is in a library written in another programming language (typically C or C++), not in your Python code.

Comment: You may want to add some prints (of the form `sys.stdout.write('MARK1\n')`), to see exactly where in your code the SIGSEGV is triggered. Maybe it's possible to make it work by doing that part a bit differently.

Comment: @pts It happens at random times, but at most I've been able to turn the camera on/off 3 times. Sadly I can't get a full score this way, because this is a part of my engineering thesis and it has to work. My task was to make a working system (machine + application) and if my way of making it doesn't work - it's sadly my fault in the eyes of the university.

Comment: @pts I added the prints, and the last one that gets printed is the one after `self.video_thread.stop()`

Comment: [mre] please. that means, reduce the code as much as humanly possible, while still causing the issue. if something isn't actually needed, remove it. that means, if you can reproduce the segfault _without_ OpenCV, or _without a thread_, then those things have to go.

Comment: you should investigate `stop()`. it's not executing in that thread's context but in the gui thread's context. right? set a flag, so the thread's loop can stop on its own.

Comment: Calling `exit()` in this case is pointless: it tells the event loop to exit, but since you're overriding `run()` then the event loop is never started at all. Setting `camera_needed` is sufficient, you may eventually consider to add `self.wait()` there, so that you can ensure that the thread has finished gracefully.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz from what I understand, I've already used a flag: `self.camera_needed` which determines whether the `while` will run.

Comment: you also call `cap.release()`, from a different thread, while a `cap.read()` is ongoing. that is sure to cause trouble. you can't just assume that everything is threadsafe. that's unreasonable. you can only take things to be threadsafe if that is guaranteed somewhere. generally, nothing is threadsafe, unless explicitly stated to be so. the media APIs of *both* operating systems throw a fit when you operate on the same video device from multiple threads.

Comment: Please answer your own question, put the solution there.

Comment: your "update 3" is wrong. you keep reinitializing the video capture in a loop. that is not okay. don't blame OpenCV.

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the question, nor change the title: this is not a forum, press the "Answer your own question" button and put the solution there. Please read [ask] and [answer].

Comment: @musicamante ok will do, sorry.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you're right, I haven't noticed it. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
    def stop(self):

        self.cap.release()
        self.camera_needed = False
        self.exit(0)
```

to:

```
    def stop(self):

        self.camera_needed = False
        self.wait()
        self.cap.release()
```

fixed the issue.

It seems, that the main problem was the order of things - I was trying to release the camera while the thread was still using its data.

Comment: Huge thanks to @musicamante for directions!